# Check for command line option in my header file

Tags: c++, g++

I want to use the gcc builtin __builtin_popcount() inside my program if, and only if, the program is compiled with the option -mpopcnt.

This is because I see that calling __builtin_popcount() when the program is *not* compiled with option -mpopcnt is actually slower than doing the popcnt() computation myself.

So I was hoping that there is a way to test whether a compilation option is present in the preprocessor. Anyone know the answer?

Comment: I'd just define a macro symbol to control whether the source uses the intrinsic.

Answer (score 2):

```
osmith@osmith-VirtualBox:~$ diff <(g++ -E -dM test.cpp) <(g++ -E -dM -mpopcnt test.cpp)
39a40
> #define __POPCNT__ 1
osmith@osmith-VirtualBox:~$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 5.3.1-14ubuntu2.1) 5.3.1 20160413
```

Clang also defines `__POPCNT__` when -mpopcnt is specified.

```
osmith@WOTSIT:~$ diff <(clang++ -E -dM test.cpp) <(clang++ -E -dM -mpopcnt test.cpp)
157a158
> #define __POPCNT__ 1
osmith@WOTSIT:~$ clang++ --version
Ubuntu clang version 3.6.0-2ubuntu1~trusty1 (tags/RELEASE_360/final) (based on LLVM 3.6.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

While it may be possible to check for compiler specific defines like "__POPCNT__" as mentioned by @kfsone, it would be easier to maintain this code if you control this within the makefile (which is expected to be compiler specific/dependent) where you use "-mpopcnt" as part of the compilation option.

eg:- (in the makefile)

```
USE_POP_CNT=y
ifeq ($(USE_POP_CNT), y)
g++ -mpopcnt -DUSE_POP_CNT=1 test.cpp
else
g++ test.cpp
endif
```

Now, in code you can do:

```
int bitcount;
#ifdef USE_POP_CNT
bitcount = __builtin_popcount(n);
#else // USE_POP_CNT
bitcount = my_popcount(n);
#endif
```